# writing " using tempo in emacs for C++

Tags: emacs

I was trying to create a template for std::cout since I am tired of writing that everytime.

This is what I wrote

```
(tempo-define-template "c++-cout"
           '("std::cout << " (p "whatTowrite: " whattowrite) " << std::endl;" > n
         )
           "cout_1"
           'c++-tempo-tags)
```

But I don't know how to print a " using the tempo. \ didn't work.

Comment: `'("std::cout << \"" (p "write: " what) "\" <<std::endl;" > n)` works for me.  How does it fail for you?

Comment: So tempo is yasnippet's granddad? TIL:)

Comment: Sorry my bad. It did work. I wish i could delete this thread !